# Suppress Message Box "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data" in Safari for online/offline webapp

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, offline.js

I have a webapp without a manifest yet that should work in both online and offline mode. I am using Offline.js to detect the network state. When first going offline a message box "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data" pops up and ends full screen mode. Is there a way to prevent iOS' Safari from this behavior?